# DDR3 Ram 1066 vs 1333?

Tags: memory, laptop

Can I install DDR3 1333 RAM into a notebook that is currently running DDR3 1066 and will it have any effect on performance?

Comment: Depends on the motherboard , check your motherboard model and see if it can support ddr3 1333 RAM

Comment: use cpuz -http://www.filehippo.com/download_cpuz/ to check your motherboard model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the memory is otherwise identical, it will work fine at the lower speed. The clock speed specified for a memory module is the MAXIMUM speed that it will work at. There is no harm in using in a system configured to go slower.

Answer (score 0):

lookup the manual on your notebook, it should mention all the different speeds of ram the motherboard supports.

Answer (score -1):

Old question, but only partially answered, as the question has two parts; the second part is “will it have any effect on performance?.

And the answer is yes. Not really noticeable under common routine tasks; but on heavy tasks, the faster speed will be noticed up to a 15% increase from 1066 to 1333 in the different stream memory tasks, as shown in the following [test](https://www.servethehome.com/memory-bandwidth-comparison-dual-xeon-e5-1066mhz-hyperspeed-memory-results/).